# Why I cannot import getcontext() from Python decimal module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I am trying to use Python decimal module for a math problem, but I cannot import anything from decimal lib. Never used this lib and cannot even get started as I cannot import anything.

Note that errors are from fresh (nothing installed) `Python 3.6.0 virtualenv` as I was thinking there was something wrong with my environment. I tested following on Python Interactive Shell on the new env.

```
from decimal import getcontext
```

error > `ImportError: cannot import name 'getcontext'`

```
from decimal import *
```

when running `getcontext().prec = 6`

I get error > `NameError: name 'getcontext' is not defined`

So there is nothing called getcontext()? decimal module also does not seem to have anything called Decimal.

Python3.6.0 documentation has getting started guide which tells me to do the following >

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Comment: Are you sure you're importing `decimal` from the stdlib?

Comment: Did you perhaps create a file called `decimal.py`?  What do you get if you do `import decimal` and then `print(decimal.__file__)`?

Comment: Thanks, @BrenBarn should have tested print(decimal.__file__) first... Actually had my own module called decimal where I had written a semi-functional version of the decimal module of my own before figured there was existing/better on standard lib..

Comment: Also thanks, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Should I close this or leave as ref how not to name your files?